# Get Child Node of next Sibling Parent Node NOT Working Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this block of HTML code.

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='/some/link' class="image"> ... </a></td>
    <td><a href="/some/link2" title="foo"> SOME TEXT </a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> some td node that appears randomly </td>
    <td><a href='/some/link' class="image"> ... </a></td>
    <td><a href="/some/link2" title="foo"> SOME TEXT </a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to get the `<td>` element that is the nextSibling of `<td>` element with `class="image"`. Appreciate someone can help me. My code below gives me undefined. Thank you.

Below, I called the `parentElement` of the node with `class="image"` and directed it to go to the nextSibling node, and get the `childNode` of that particular node, and finally get the text. I don't understand why it does not work.

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr > td > a.image');
return Array.prototype.map.call(nodes, function(e) {
    return e.parentElement.nextSibling.childNodes[1].a.innerText;
}
```

Site Url : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_Peace_Prize_laureates 
[Screenshot of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie47i.jpg)

I am intending to grab all the names of the Nobel Prize winners.

Answer (score 0):

Following will work

```
Array.prototype.map.call(nodes, function(e) {
    return e.parentElement.nextElementSibling.childNodes[1].innerText;
})
```

**EDIT :**

Based on given wiki link, we can do it in different ways, one of them as below.

Assuming each `tr` will contain name

```
var trs = document.querySelectorAll('.wikitable tr');// 'tbody > tr > td > a.image' will give a.image inside single tr also which may fail

Array.prototype.reduce.call(trs,function(result,tr){
 var e = tr.querySelector('td .image')
 if(e && e.parentElement.nextElementSibling)
    result.push(e.parentElement.nextElementSibling.querySelector('a').innerText);
  return result;
},[])
```

Comment: Hi @Jags. Thanks for your answer. I believe your answer is correct but somehow it does not work. It gives me null. I've edited my question to include the link of the page and a screenshot of the exact code.

Comment: @Ming edited the answer, you may need handle more cases.